# Selenuim ChromeDriverManager Erorr

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, error-handling, driver

Pretty much instead of me doing a local exe for chrome I want to use an online version but I keep going into this error. I've removed "service=s" with that being gone that removes the ability to use it online.

**Code:**

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("google.com")

time.sleep(1000)
```

**Error:** `File "c:\Users\andre\Desktop\balls.py", line 14, in <module> driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s) TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you use older version which doesn't use service. And it may need `webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

Comment: What selenium version you are using?

Comment: I will make sure I format my question better next time but I think your correct on the selenium version. It would work in Idea Ultimite not VSC and pyinstaller on my pc but on my laptop it seems to work fine here. I know this is a Google question but how can I change my version. Thank you for helping

Comment: I normally runs `pip install --upgrade selenium` to get newer version. Or shorter with upper `U` and single `-`  like `pip install -U selenium`

Comment: thank you i just uninstalled it then installed it